# Debugging of Chromecast

Tags: casting, remote-debugging, chromecast

I have implemented an Android application, which is for playing movies via GoogleCast. Everything works fine, but I need to enable a Chrome Remote Debugger.

I found an article [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging). I proceeded step by step according to instructions in this article, but I can see nothing in console.

IP address of my Chromecast is `10.0.0.36`. In Chrome, I go to http://10.0.0.36:9222. The page is displayed and it looks like this:

[image]

I click on link **Remote Debugging (AppEngine)** and then I see the console. I type `cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);` to this console.

[image]

According to instructions in article mentioned above, that's all and now it should work, but I can see anything in console.

Could you tell me, please, what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your URL bar, there should be a shield icon towards the right side. Click on that and enable scripts.